# Get html attribute inside Thymeleaf link

Tags: thymeleaf

In html you can define your own attributes by data prefix.

With thymleaf this would look like e.g. th:data-version="${version}" .

Now I have a link and want to use this value. In javascript you get it by using this.getAttribute('data-version') function.

How can I use it in this thymeleaf link(Right now it does not work):

'window.location.href = \'' + @{/api/author/testcase?version=} + this.getAttribute(data-version) +'\''

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, when something doesn't work, give us as much details as possible so that we can help you, like an error trace if there is one, or a description of the erratic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in Thymeleaf.  There is no way to access the `data` attributes of tags with Thymeleaf.

If you want to use the same value in 2 different places, then it must be a Thymeleaf variable.  For example, if you've defined `${version}` on the model.

```
<div th:data-version="${version}">
    .
    .
    .
</div>

<div th:data-url="@{/api/author/testcase(version=${version})}" onclick="window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-url');">
    Click Me
<div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. I really wouldn't have known how to do it. My whole project was in danger. So thanks a lot.